# A question about SQL insert statement!

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have two tables:

```
Threads
*******
ThreadID
UserID
TopicsID
Date
ThreadTitle
ThreadParagraph
ThreadClosed

Topics
******
TopicID
Theme
Topics
Date
```

I need to insert two statements and connect between them!
This the first statment:

```
string insertCommand = 
    "INSERT INTO Users (UserID,TopicID,Date,ThreadTitle,ThreadParagraph) " +
     "VALUES ('CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '" + giveMeGuidID() + 
     "),TopicID,dateTime,questionTitle,subTopic)";
```

and i need to have another statement for the Topics Table:

```
string insertCommand = 
    "INSERT INTO Topics (UserID,TopicID,Date,ThreadTitle,ThreadParagraph) " +
    "VALUES ('Theme, Topics, Date')";
```

The problem is that i have a connection between TopicsID (Threads table) and TopicsID
(Topics table). Both are incremental ints, so how do i insert the same TopicID to 
both of them so they get the same value?

Comment: can you give a little more detail about how you are calling those insert commands. personally, i would create a stored proc - this would be able to return the created ID using `@@identity`

Comment: Here's the link to what @guagland is suggesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but I prefer using a data access layer that handles this automatically, e.g. linq-to-sql.

Comment: i would rather neglect the whole idea of linq

Answer (score 2):

If you use MS SQL server, you can get the autoincrement value with @@Identity.

```
string insertCommand = 
    "INSERT INTO Users (UserID,TopicID,Date,ThreadTitle,ThreadParagraph) " +
    "VALUES ('CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '" + giveMeGuidID() +
    "),TopicID,dateTime,questionTitle,subTopic); SELECT @@Identity";
```

Then, run this command as ExecuteScalar and get your value

Comment: or create a stored procedure that will insert 2 rows at once in a transaction

Comment: @@Identity gets the last identity that was inserted. SQL Server can be serving many applications simultaneously so @@Identity may give you back the identity of something that someone else was doing if they manage to get their INSERT statement in between your INSERT and SELECT. Use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead.

Comment: so you use @@Select to get the identity. Is the identity an "int" that i can feed into another sql insert statement that will insert TopicID in the Topic table. What do i do with the Select @@identity

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain the `Transaction` by using `TransactionScope` and using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the inserted Id from the First Query.

```
 // Create the TransactionScope
using (TransactionScope oTranScope = new TransactionScope())
{
   Int32 TopicID;
    // Open a connection 
    using (SqlConnection oCn1 = new SqlConnection(this.sCn1))
    {
        SqlCommand oCmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (UserID,TopicID,Date,ThreadTitle,ThreadParagraph) " +
"VALUES ('CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '" + giveMeGuidID() +
"),TopicID,dateTime,questionTitle,subTopic); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";, oCn1);

        oCmd1.Parameters.Add ... Better to use parameter to save SQL Injection Attack

        oCn1.Open();
        // At this point, the connection is in the transaction scope, 
        // which is a lightweight transaction.
        TopicID = Convert.ToInt32 oCmd1.ExecuteScaler()); // as you want to get Id
        oCn1.Close();
    }
    // Open a connection 
    using (SqlConnection oCn2 = new SqlConnection(this.sCn2))
    {
        SqlCommand oCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SQLQuery", oCn2);
        //use return TopicID from last inserted query
        oCn2.Open();
        // The connection is enlisted in the transaction scope, 
        // which is now promoted to a distributed transaction
        // controlled by MSDTC
        oCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oCn2.Close();
    }
    // Tell the transaction scope to commit when ready 
    oTranScope.Consistent = true;
    // The following bracket completes and disposes the transaction
}
```

Comment: What do u do with the topicID, and shouldnt there be 2 sql statement. another sql statement that inserts the TopicID with the topicParagraph, topicTitle and Date?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something reliable you need to use *Transactions*.

Refer to [Managing Transactions in SQL Server Stored Procedures](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513004758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080305-1.shtml) to get an idea.

Also, take a look at [Controlling Transactions (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175523.aspx) and [SQL Server Transaction Isolation Models](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/isolationmodels.htm).

You also need to use [@@Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) the last-inserted identity value.

Answer (score 0):

You code samples do not correlate well with the rest of the information provided. Without the code your post seems consistent enough, though, so I'm inclined to consider those snippets as simply erroneous.

Anyway, your idea seems clear. In SQL Server 2005+ you could solve your problem with an INSERT statement like this one:

```
string insertCommand = 
    "INSERT INTO Topics (Theme, Topics, Date) " +
      "OUTPUT 'CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '" + giveMeGuidID() +
      "'), INSERTED.TopicID, @dateTime, @questionTitle, @subTopic " +
      "INTO Threads (UserID, TopicID, Date, ThreadTitle, ThreadParagraph) " +
    "VALUES (@Theme, @Topics, @Date)";
```

Although this is a single statement, it performs two inserts into different tables. The 'main' insert is being made into the `Topics` table. The 'secondary' one, into `Threads`, is defined by the `OUTPUT...INTO` clause. Basically, the [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause allows you to reference the data being inserted and either return them as a rowset to the client, or (when combined with `INTO`) direct them into an existing table, like you can see it done here.